# Bootstrap navbar disappered

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm working on a website made with `Bootstrap 3.3.4`.

I have an issue with a navbar, all links work but aren't visible and I don't know why?

I'm working with Dreamweaver CC 2020. Anyone can understand where is the issue?

Thank you all very much.

Here there is a code

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top one-page-nav-scrolling one-page-nav__fixed one-page-header " data-role="navigation">
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu-container page-scroll navbar-header">

  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"> 
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
      <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#body"> 
        <img src="img_CM/marchio/logo_cm.png" alt="cmcapoferri" class="img-responsive"> 
    </a> 
    </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <div class="menu-container">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-header">
        <li class="page-scroll"> <a href="#About"><span data-hover="About">chi siamo</span></a> </li>
        <li class="page-scroll"> <a href="#WhyWe"><span data-hover="Why We">Storia</span></a> </li>
        <li class="page-scroll"> <a href="#Services"><span data-hover="Services">Servizi</span></a> </li>
        <li class="page-scroll"> <a href="#WorkProcess"><span data-hover="Work Process">produzione</span></a> </li>
        <li class="page-scroll"> <a href="#Skills"><span data-hover="Skills">automotive</span></a> </li>
        <li class="page-scroll"> <a href="#Team"><span data-hover="Team">laboratorio</span></a> </li>
        <li class="page-scroll"> <a href="#Testimonials"><span data-hover="Testimonials">clienti</span></a> </li>
        <li class="page-scroll"> <a href="#Contact"><span data-hover="Contact">Contatti</span></a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse --> 
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: Works fine here - https://www.bootply.com/ncLwD8EMuO Must be a styling issue or render issue with dreamweaver as a guess. What device are you working on although there should not be a problem here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :) Finally I figured out the mistake. Issue was visibility:hidden and I changed it in visibility:visible and add z-index:1.